# mongodb MongoTemplate withWriteConcern how?

Tags: mongodb

Service
session.startTransaction();

DAO
db.getCollection("test").withWriteConcern(WriteConcern.MAJORITY);
target.insertOne(session,contents);

Service
session.commitTransaction();

how to

MongoTemplate  withWriteConcern???

I'm curious how to withWriteConcern from mongotemplate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `MongoTemplate`'s method [setWriteConcern](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html#setWriteConcern-com.mongodb.WriteConcern-)
 to specify the write concern for your write action on the MongoDB collection.

From Spring-Data MongoDB documentation on `WriteConcern`:

> [10.4.3.
>   WriteConcern](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template.writeconcern): 
>   If it has not yet been specified through the driver at a higher level
>   (such as com.mongodb.MongoClient), you can set the
>   com.mongodb.WriteConcern property that the MongoTemplate uses for
>   write operations. If the WriteConcern property is not set, it defaults
>   to the one set in the MongoDB driver’s DB or Collection setting.

Another way of configuring the write concern on `MongoTemplate` is by using the `WriteConcernResolver` interface.

From Spring-Data MongoDB documentation on `WriteConcernResolver`:

> [10.4.4.
>   WriteConcernResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template.writeconcernresolver):
>   For more advanced cases where you want to set different WriteConcern
>   values on a per-operation basis (for remove, update, insert, and save
>   operations), a strategy interface called WriteConcernResolver can be
>   configured on MongoTemplate. Since MongoTemplate is used to persist
>   POJOs, the WriteConcernResolver lets you create a policy that can map
>   a specific POJO class to a WriteConcern value...

- [MongoTemplate#setWriteConcernResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html#setWriteConcernResolver-org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.WriteConcernResolver-)
- [WriteConcernResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/WriteConcernResolver.html)